# Are there restrictions to Bot Event Logs on Developer Orgs?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, eventlogfile

I am having an issue where no event logs are created for conversations with Einstein bots in my developer org. I am able to get a session ID for each conversation, but when I open the event logs under the 'Performance' tab, it is completely blank. I've made sure to check the box to enable logging conversations in the 'Overview' tab. Additionally, when I query the ConversationDefinitionEventLog, no results are returned. Is there a special process for enabling event logs on a developer org?

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed itself; I checked back the next day and suddenly all the event logs were there.